# Deduce kernel of isogeny from action on torsion points

Tags: nt.number-theory, elliptic-curves, computational-number-theory, cryptography, software

I'm stuck with the following problem:

In Petit's work "[Faster Algorithms for Isogeny Problems using Torsion Point Images](https://eprint.iacr.org/2017/571)", p. 8, he says that we can deduce $\ker \psi_{N_2}$ knowing the action of $\psi = \psi_{N_1'}\circ\psi_{N_2}$ on $E[N_2],$ where $\psi_{N_1'}$ and $\psi_{N_2}$ are isogenies of degree respectively $N_1'$ and $N_2$ and $\psi = \psi_{N_1'}\circ\psi_{N_2}$ an endomorphism on the elliptic curve $E$.

Well, I don't understand this statement. I've tried writing $[N_2] = \psi_{N_2}\circ \hat{\psi}_{N_2}$ and then fiddling with the expressions, but to no avail.

I have a feeling this problem is easy, but I'm stuck  and would appreciate any help/ideas.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The key details here are

1. $N_2$ is "smooth by assumption", so solving discrete logarithms in $E[N_2]$ is supposed to be easy (using Pohlig-Hellman; how easy this is depends on how smooth $N_2$ is).
2. $\gcd(N_1,N_2) = 1$, so the kernel of $\psi_2$ is equal to the kernel of the restriction of $\psi$ to $E[N_2]$.

Now, if you evaluate $\psi$ on a basis of $E[N_2]$, then by solving
discrete logarithms you can view the restriction of $\psi$ to
$E[N_2]$ as a matrix over $\mathbb{Z}/N_2\mathbb{Z}$, and then
computing the kernel (and hence the kernel of $\psi_2$) is a matter of linear algebra.

Comment: I think that i understood the second part: let $\psi|_{E[N_2]} : E[N_2] \to E[N_2](?)$ and $\{P,Q\}$ one basis of $E[N_2].$ Then i can write $\psi(P) = a_{11}P+a_{12}Q$ and $\psi(Q)=a_{21}P + a_{22}Q$ with $a_{ij} \in \mathbb{Z}/N_2\mathbb{Z}$ and I calculate the kernel as usual in such cases. I also understand  why $\ker \psi_{N_2}\subseteq \ker \psi|_{E[N_2]},$ but not why  $\ker \psi|_{E[N_2]}\subseteq \ker \psi_{N_2}$

Comment: Since $\gcd(N_1',N_2) = 1$, the isogeny $\psi_{N_1'}$ restricts to an isomorphism on $N_2$-torsion; so $\psi(R) = 0$ for some $R$ in $E[N_2]$ iff $\psi_{N_2}(R) = 0$.